# Подзапрос к Dictionary, Linq. Получить Max по Value, и Min по Key

Tags: c#, linq

У меня спортивный интерес, как сделать следующий запрос более лаконичным. И вообще понять как осуществляются подзапросы в linq к такой коллекции как `Dictionary`.

#### Задача:

Получить из коллекции `Dictionary<int,int>` элемент с самым большим Value, если будет несколько элементов с максимальным Value, то получить все.
Затем из полученной коллекции если элементов больше одного, взять тот у которого самый маленький Key.

Из-за своего невежества, я создал такого монстра, подскажите как сделать красиво и менее многословно,желательно все уместить в единый запрос, а не как у меня в два.

```
Dictionary<int,int> d = new Dictionary<int,int>();
var q1 = from a1 in d
         where a1.Value == d.Values.Max()
         select a1;
var q2 = (from a2 in q1
          where a2.Key == (from a3 in q1 select a3.Key).Min()
          select a2).First();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вроде бы не монстр :) :

```
var result = d.OrderByDescending(n => n.Value).ThenBy(m => m.Key).First();
```

Или как вариант:

```
var result = (from n in d orderby n.Value descending, n.Key select n).First();
```

Comment: все работает, спасибо. Только я не пойму как мы получаем минимум по ``Key``?

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov, мы просто сортируем по двум полям, по `Value` с убыванием (`descending`), по `Key` с возрастанием. А потом берем первое значение.

Comment: все гениальное просто) спасибо еще раз)